# NodeJS + RxDB + Electron w/ persistent data

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I have been playing around with [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) (using express-pouchdb and pouchdb-find) for a while and realized that I needed to work with some streams through Rxjs for my Angular 5/Electron app.

For my current setup, I run [express-pouchdb](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server#express-pouchdb) to set up a localized PouchDB for persistence and then in Angular I have the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class PouchdbService {
    private _localdb = 'http://localhost:3000/main';
    private _pouchDb: any;

  constructor() {
    this._pouchDb = new PouchDB(this._localdb);
    PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);

    this.createIndexes();
  }

  private createIndexes(): void {
    this._pouchDb.createIndex({
        index: {
            fields: [ 'tags' ]
        }
    });

    this._pouchDb.createIndex({
        index: {
            fields: [ 'date' ]
        }
    })

    this._pouchDb.createIndex({
        index: {
            fields: [ 'title' ]
        }
    });
  }
```

This provides my service to the express app through `_localdb` property. I could keep the `PouchDB` express app and just call it through RxDB by rewriting my service and refactoring the code. However, I guess that I need have to call [sync](https://pubkey.github.io/rxdb/rx-collection.html#sync) on every collection.

Though, I would rather drop the express application if there was a way to run with persistence with RxDB directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [websql adapter](https://pubkey.github.io/rxdb/rx-database.html#adapter) which apparently stores information between application loads and dropped [express-pouchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-pouchdb).